# Help in 2d platform script

Tags: unity, 2d

Now I finished my 2d game but when I set up it in my mobile it becomes like this so I change some scripts in Maincamera but it's still the same
[image]

How can I change the screen to become horizontal in my mobile like this?
[image]
what I need that how can I make it fit my mobile screen.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the property in the Player settings:

`Edit -> Project settings -> Player`

In the inspector will be a tab for each Player your project supports.
You have to change the `Default orientation` to landscape:

[image]